# Why won't my jQuery form resubmit?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So I have done this a few times and it has worked, but for some reason my form won't work this time. When I submit the form jQuery uses mail.php to do one final validation. It then either submits it or echoes the form back with errors.

So basically when I submit the form with errors, it will echo it back with the respective errors, but when I correct the values and try to resubmit, it won't resubmit.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Form Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#email').keypress(function() {
                p = {};
                p['email'] = document.getElementById("email").value;
                $("#emailcheck").load("validate_email.php", p);
            });

            $('#message').keypress(function() {
                p = {};
                p['message'] = document.getElementById("message").value;
                $("#messagecheck").load("validate_message.php", p);
            });

                $('#mail').click(function() {

                    p = {};
                    p['email'] = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    p['message'] = document.getElementById("message").value;
                    $("#body").load("mail.php", p);

                });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <table style="display: block;" id="body">
        <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </td>
            <td id="emailcheck"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td id="messagecheck"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><input id="mail" type="submit" value="Email" onclick="return false;"/></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: are you sure that mail.php isn't just throwing an error? There is very little error handling if something goes wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here:

```
$("#body").load("mail.php", p);
```

You're replacing the entire content for `#body`. That includes all the elements that you've bound callbacks to so all those callbacks are lost. That probably leaves with just `onclick="return false;"` as the action for `#mail` so your form is dead.

You can bind your callbacks with [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or rebind all your handlers when you replace `#body`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind the event handler for the button (`#mail`),  or just use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

When you load back in the HTML, the event bound to that element is lost.

Also, `p` isn't scoped to the function, therefore it *would* persist those properties, (had you not explicitly reassigned it to an empty object literal).

**Always** prefix your variable definitions with `var` unless you really need an implied global (99.9% the time you do not).