# Login page using jquery does not resubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The problem is that on a login page, after an incorrect entry is submitted, the ajax request does not go through a second time on pressing submit.

I have hunted through StackExchange for an answer to my question, and have looked at links such as [Why won't my jQuery form resubmit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142851/why-wont-my-jquery-form-resubmit) and [jQuery & AJAX login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271880/jquery-ajax-login-form?rq=1) among a dozen others. Looks like I need to unbind the submitted variables, but not sure how to do this.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b">    
    <h1>My login</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content">
    <form method="post" id="loginform">
        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  />
        <label for="passwd">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" value=""  />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /login page -->
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#loginform").on('submit',function(event){
    var $form = $(this),
      serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // fire off the request to /form.py
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://mywebsite/cgi-bin/form.py",
      type: "post",
      data: serializedData,

      // callback handler that will be called on success
      success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(response);
        // If login is unsuccessful, log message and return to login screen again
        if (response == "INVALID_USER\n") {
          alert("sorry, try again");
        } else {
          // Login successful - do something
        }
      },

      // callback handler that will be called on error
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(
          "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown);
      },

      // callback handler that will be called on completion
      // which means, either on success or error
      complete: function(){
        //----- DO I NEED TO UNBIND SOMETHING HERE?
        var dummy = 1;
      }
    }); // end of ajax call
}); // end of submit handler
});
```

Comment: have you put alert in javascript to debug it? Where is the problem?

Comment: Yes the alert is there to debug. The problem is that, if the login fails and I resubmit the form, it doesn't work - the server request never goes through.

Comment: OK tell me one thing, is your page display through cgi? are you run your page through any board?

Comment: Nope, this is hardcoded on a mobile app and it calls a web server to get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try to add `return false` before the end of the event handler? Using return false you prevent the event fire and prevent the user from proceeding without filling out the correct required fields.

```
$("#loginform").on('submit',function(event){

    ...

    return false;
});
```

Furthermore what data type is returned by the server? For example if the server returns JSON then you should add `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX code. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

Maybe you could use the [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/el/firefox/addon/firebug/) to find out whether any error occurs.

Comment: No luck - have tried that before, even inside the success handler.

Comment: The return false is required at the end of the event handler. I've also updated my answer with possible error causes. Thnx